# Repeating an expression group

Tags: regex

```
([a-z]+\w*){5}
```

Above expression matches every text that:

1. **Has at least 5 a-z characters**
2. Has not begun with non a-z characters

and that's not what I want to express.

It doesn't care about whole string length *(It matches "abc123456deftjfklajdfkj239")*

I want an expression that matches with a text that :

1. **starts with a-z characters**
2. Continues with word characters
3. whole string's length won't be more than 5 character

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use anchors to do this:

```
^[a-z]\w{,4}$
```

http://rubular.com/r/xdqYajifZa

Comment: Your range quantifier is invalid. I would change it to `{0,4}`

Comment: @hwnd depends on the engine; some support `{,4}` but I think `{0,4}` would be more widely supported

Comment: that's awesome but what if I want [a-z] part be necessary to exist and \w part optional and whole string still up to 5 characters?